Turbo Stream Not Updating View After CSV Upload - Need to Refresh the Page Manually
I'm working on a Rails 8.0 app that uses Turbo Streams to dynamically update certain sections of the page after uploading a CSV file. However, after I upload the CSV and process the data, the page does not automatically update with the new content. I have to manually refresh the page to see the changes.
Here’s what I have so far:
Code in the Controller (ProductsController):
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  require 'csv'

  def index
    @csv_data = session[:csv_data] || []  # Load uploaded CSV data from session
  end

  def import
    if params[:file].present?
      csv_file = params[:file]
      @csv_data = []

      CSV.foreach(csv_file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        relevant_data = {
          "sku_code" => row["sku_code"],
          "product_id" => row["product_id"],
          "product_title" => row["product_title"],
          "sell_price" => row["sell_price"],
          "tax_rate" => row["tax_rate"],
          "suppliers" => parse_supplier_data(row)
        }
        @csv_data << relevant_data
      end

      session[:csv_data] = @csv_data

      respond_to do |format|
        format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: [
          turbo_stream.replace("products_table", partial: "products_table", locals: { csv_data: @csv_data }),
          turbo_stream.replace("action_buttons", partial: "action_buttons")
        ]}
        format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: "CSV uploaded and parsed successfully." }
      end
    else
      redirect_to products_path, alert: "Please upload a valid CSV file."
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    Rails.logger.error "Error processing CSV: #{e.message}"
    redirect_to products_path, alert: "Error processing CSV: #{e.message}"
  end

  def clear
    session[:csv_data] = nil  # Clear the CSV data stored in the session
    redirect_to products_path, notice: "Data cleared. You can upload a new CSV."
  end

  private

  def parse_supplier_data(row)
    suppliers = []
    supplier_columns = row.headers.select { |col| col.match?(/supplier_\d+_/) }
    supplier_ids = supplier_columns.map { |col| col[/supplier_(\d+)_/, 1] }.uniq

    supplier_ids.each do |supplier_id|
      suppliers << {
        "supplier_id" => row["supplier_#{supplier_id}_id"],
        "supplier_name" => row["supplier_#{supplier_id}_name"],
        "supplier_cost" => row["supplier_#{supplier_id}_cost"],
        "supplier_ref" => row["supplier_#{supplier_id}_ref"]
      }
    end

    suppliers
  end
end

Code in the View (index.html.erb):
erb
<h1>Manage Supplier Associations</h1>

<% if @csv_data.blank? %>
  <!-- File Upload Form -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3>Upload a CSV File</h3>
      <%= form_with url: import_products_path, method: :post, multipart: true, class: "mb-4" do |f| %>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <%= f.file_field :file, class: "form-control", accept: ".csv" %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.submit "Upload CSV", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <!-- Table Section -->
  <div id="products_table">
    <%= render partial: "products_table", locals: { csv_data: @csv_data } %>
  </div>

  <!-- Buttons Section -->
  <div id="action_buttons" class="mt-3">
    <%= link_to "Export CSV", export_products_path, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    <%= link_to "Clear Data", clear_products_path, method: :get, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

roblem:
When I upload the CSV and it is processed, the Turbo Stream updates the table and buttons, but the changes do not appear until I manually refresh the page. I expect the page to automatically update without the need for a manual refresh after the file is uploaded.
What I have tried:
Using redirect_to after uploading the file to re-render the page.
Wrapping the Turbo Stream updates in turbo_stream.replace to replace the relevant elements (products_table and action_buttons).
Ensuring that the Turbo Stream is properly set up in my controller.
Ensuring the partials are being rendered correctly with the updated @csv_data.
What I need help with:
Why does the page not automatically update after the CSV is uploaded?
How can I make sure the page updates without needing a manual refresh?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

There are multiple problems with this controller which is going to make addressing the main issue very difficult. The overarching one is that it's doing way to much - move the CSV parsing steps into a separate class so that you can test them in isolation. Divide and conquer. session[:csv_data] = @csv_data is highly problematic if you're using the default cookie based session storage as it will cause the cookie to overflow.

Indescrimately catching high level errors (rescue StandardError => e) is a known anti-pattern known as "Pokemon Exception Handling". What you're doing is just making a black hole that swallows exceptions you should not be catching which makes debugging very difficult.

you need to do turbo_stream.update instead of replace. you do not have a target <div id="products_table"> rendered when the form is visible, there is nothing for turbo to update on the page at that time.
